# Mocking **class** with generic interface and methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, mocking, moq

I have to mock a template method in a class. I am writing test for legacy code and have no possibility to change the code.

The interface looks like:

```cs
public interface ICommand<in I, out O>
    {
        O Execute(I input);
    }
```

The implementation:

```cs
public class GetCaseCommand : ICommand<string, Task<EsdhCaseResponseDto>>
{
     public Task<EsdhCaseResponseDto> Execute(string input)
     {
         return ExecuteInternal(input);
     }
}
```

I have to Mock that method from the **class** because (the Mock of) the class has to be a constructor parameter for another class, which will not accept the interface.

I have tried this test:

```cs
var mockGetCaseCommand = 
      new Mock<GetCaseCommand>(mockCommandGetLogger.Object, mockedEsdhService.Object);

mockGetCaseCommand.Setup(mGC => mGC.Execute(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult<EsdhCaseResponseDto>(new EsdhCaseResponseDto()
                {
                    Title = "Title",
                    CaseId = "123456"
                }));
```

And get the exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: mGC => mGC.Execute(It.IsAny())
> Non-overridable members (here: GetCaseCommand.Execute) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

I have tried to find other ways to create the Setup. But the one above, is the only one which I can get compiled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are attempting mocking a concrete class `GetCaseCommand` and a non-virtual implementation `Execute`. You need to mock the interface instead. If you want to mock the concrete class, you need to make the method virtual.

Comment: @AnuViswan, thanks for your comment. I have edited the question. I can't use the interface because the Mock/class has to be used as constructing parameter for another class, which not accept the interface. And i can't change the original code :-(. Is the conclusion that the test is impossible ?

Comment: That's exactly the problem with using concrete type dependencies rather than abstractions - it's hard to test. So if introducing an interface is not an option you should make `Execute` method `virtual` - this should be the least destructive change for legacy code.

Comment: @AndersFinnJørgensen The other class is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make mocking the dependency difficult.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite clear about your use-case. Which part of the code can you modify? If you can modify `GetCaseCommand`, maybe you can make its method virtual and mock it. If you can modify the classes that depend on `GetCaseCommand`, maybe you make them depend on `ICommand` so you can mock the interface. If you can not modify all of the above... it sounds strange to me because you cannot do anything when the tests fail.

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing is a mean, not a goal.

If changing legacy code is out of question, you should accept the fact that your parent class is not purely testable and treat `GetCaseCommand` as internal behavior.

What might help you to keep a high degree of unit-testability is making what I call "second degree mocking", that is mock `GetCaseCommand`'s dependencies (logger, service), which from your code snippets I infer they are represented as interfaces.

And if second degree mocking is also not possible - just do integration tests.